# org.postgresql.util.PGobject to org.postgis.Point;

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, sqlgeography

Do you know how can convert the type of PGobject to Point in Java?
Actually PGobject is an object like this:
PGobject geolocation:

```
type: geography
value: 0101000020E6100000C006335CD3043840504BBDB89EC14140
```

How can convert this number into Point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is below and it works fine, but I think that your solution is better

```
String g = geolocation.getValue();
try {
    Geometry fr = new PGgeometry().geomFromString(g);
    Point p = fr.getPoint(0);
    this.geolocation = p;
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: My solution is actually wrong, because it returns a Point of type com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point, but you need a Point of type PGgeometry (from the Postgis driver). So your solution is the correct one

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean a [jts](http://geotools.org/) Point?

If yes so use WkbReader, because your geometry is in  [well-know-binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) format:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKBReader;


WKBReader wkbReader = new WKBReader();
byte[] geom = wkbReader.hexToBytes('0101000020E6100000C006335CD3043840504BBDB89EC14140');
System.out.println(wkbReader.read(geom));     
// prints POINT (24.01885010000001 35.5126563)
```

The result is of type `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point`